# What is the reason behind the necessity of stationarity of an interior solution to finding local extrema?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I understand that for concave and convex functions in $\Re^n$, the extremum will occur at a stationary point and that concavity/convexity guarantees the existence of such a point whenever there is an interior solution; but I don't understand how we can confidently exclude a case where a function does not have any stationary points (e.g. A case where the function is stationary at one or more coordinate(s) in some neighborhood of its domain, but never stationary at all coordinates) but still has an interior solution on some subset of $\Re^n$?

EDIT: I've worked on this some more, and it seems like a function as described above would not have an interior solution, can anyone confirm this or direct me to a formal proof?

Comment: What do you mean by "in some neighborhood of its domain"? Don't you consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ as the domain?

Comment: I mean that I'm allowing for the possibility of a zero derivative of some but not all coordinates  in a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a zero derivative for other coordinates in another such subset where both subsets have no intersection

Comment: Concavity/convexity does not guarantee the existence of a stationary point. Consider (nonzero) linear functions as an example. Why do you talk about "interior solution" when the domain is $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Good points; I'll modify the question to be more precise